# Set up DryIoc with an old asp.net mvc (not core)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dryioc

I have an old Asp.net mvc application using Microsoft.aspnet mvc 5.2.7

I would like to use DryIoc but I could not find any example on how to use it.

I have added the DryIoc.MVC nuget but with somehow does not see any "WithMVC" extentions. Am I missing something?

1. How do you set up DryIoc with an old asp.net mvc ?
2. What are the correct nuget to use?

Any examples?

Also what is the difference between these two
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .dll package. Here is the doc listing all extensions: https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/Extensions.md#extensions-and-companions

For some reason (time passed) I could not quickly find a complete sample. There is the latest thing here https://github.com/vmrocha/dryioc.web without using any extensions. But it's fine because DryIocMvc.cs is quite small without the docs https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/src/DryIoc.Mvc/DryIocMvc.cs

There are also the tests to see the API usage https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/tree/master/test/DryIoc.Mvc.UnitTests